# Issue trying to install zoom

Tags: boot

Unfortunately I have a low-resource computer and I took on the task of installing MX Linux, unfortunately I am not a professional on Linux, I have tried to install zoom, which is where I receive my classes, but it gives me many errors, I have downloaded the packages that end in .deb and nothing, I only managed to install Microsoft Edge, but not zoom.

Comment: Please write in English. This forum uses the English language.

Comment: unfortunately I have a low-income computer and I take the duty to install MX Linux, unfortunately I am not a professional in linux, I have tried to install zoom that there I receive my classes but throws me many errors, I have downloaded the packages that end in .dev and nothing, I only manage to install microsoft edge, but the zoom does not, and if you urge me, thank you very much

Comment: We can help with Ubuntu and Ubuntu family flavours. The lightweight flavours Lubuntu and Xubuntu might work in the computers where you try with MX Linux. -- Unfortunately we cannot help you with non-Ubuntu Linux distros. Please try at a dedicated forum for MXLinux or at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you want to ask on Unix & Linux, they are going to want to know what errors you are receiving as well as the steps needed to reproduce those errors.

Comment: Usted hay intentado instalar con **sudo snap install zoom-client**?

Comment: I just tried and it works
" sudo: snap: command not found

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: FYI:  I QA-test the *lightweight* distributions of Ubuntu using equipment from 2005 & newer, those are on-topic here, MX Linux is not Ubuntu and thus off-topic here; so use an appropriate site for your chosen OS, or if you wish to use this site; use an appropriate OS - Ubuntu has pretty good & numerous support sites; you've chosen another OS so use its sites.  If your *old* machine is older than 2005; I used older hardware in releases up to 19.04 but not the *modern* releases.

Answer (score 1):

First install snapd

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

You can try to install it with the command bellow:

Usted puede intentar instalar con el comando abajo:

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

Comment: And if you already have the `zoom_amd64.deb` file [one way is](https://itsfoss.com/install-deb-files-ubuntu/) is `sudo apt install zoom_amd64.deb`